# Grails how to set _idx field when INSERTing data from outside of the Grails application?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a scaffolded Grails application with two domains, Person and Course. Person belongs to Course, and Course hasMany Persons. I have modified show.gsp for Course to list all of the Persons associated with the selected Course.

To achieve this, Course.groovy contains the following line:

```
List persons = new ArrayList()
```

And, as a result, the "person" database table contains a persons_idx field. I frequently will be adding new data to the "person" table *outside* of my Grails application, from an external website.

When INSERTing new data, how to I figure out what to set persons_idx as?

I had originally used a SortedSet instead of an ArrayList for persons, since I care about sorting. But since I am sorting on Person.lastName, and there will always be multiple people with the same last name, then the list will exclude those persons who have the same last names as others. I wish there was another way...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having two applications manipulate the same Database is a thing to avoid, when possible.  Can your 2nd application instead call an action on the controlling app to add a Person to the Course with parameters passed to specify each?  That way, only one app is writing to the DB, reducing caching, index, and sequence headaches.

You also state that Person belongsTo Course... so you create a new Person for "Bob Jenkins" for each course that he's in?  This seems excessive.  You should probably look into a ManyToMany for this.

Without moving to a service, unfortunately, you'd want to change the indices on some if not many of the rows for the children of the Course you're trying to add a Person to, as that index is the sorted index for all the Persons in the Course.

I would suggest going back to a "Set", and do your sorting in the app.  Your other question about sorting already told you not to override compareTo to just check the last name.  If I were you, I'd forget about overriding compareTo at all (except to check IDs, if you want), and just use the sort() method, passing in a closure that correctly sorts the objects.

Comment: Ultimately, yes, I really do need to introduce a service layer that each of my applications can use to talk with the database. I'm just not there yet. I would explore the Many to Many, but with my requirements, "Bob Jenkins" can only ever sign up for one Course.

Comment: "not being there yet" isn't very far away with Grails.  Essentially, most controllers are already "almost"-RESTful services.  The hard part is getting your other app to be able to hit your Grails app with arguments using HttpClient or some such rather than hit the DB directly.

Comment: I edited a bit to address your current issue, rather than the far-off stuff.

Comment: Thanks. What are your thoughts on the solution in the following article...(http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1029)? It recommends that instead of using a Collection of Persons in Course, to instead add "Course course" to Person. I find that this works for me, although I haven't quite been able to wrap my head around why it works, exactly. With this solution, I am able to achieve the sorting within the show.gsp page.

Comment: Sure, Burt's a smart guy.  You're essentially writing your own oneToMany at that point, but that's not that hard.  You can code your own cascading delete, etc.